# How do you insert a list in a sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite

I only know how to enter strings and numbers, but is there a way to enter a list? Basically, I have a dictionary and each key is being put into the database. The value to each key is a list and I want this in the database as well.

Comment: Do you want to enter the list as one entry or as a table?  If it is a table then either use repeated inserts or a block insert.  See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html - have a look at the syntax of the VALUES part

Answer (score 1):

SQLite3 does not have array data type. (See [Datatypes in SQLite version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html))

But, you can serialize to insert it to sqlite3 table.

For example, you can convert the list into json string, and use the string to insert into the table. ([`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps))

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO a_table (..., a_list_field) values (..., ?)',
               [..., json.dumps(a_list_object)])
```

When you select it, convert it back to list by loading json string. ([`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads))

Answer (score 0):

With sqlite3 I was able to execute this script that drops a database and rewrites it with new data using a list named `data`. This may or may not answer your specific question:

```
from views import db
from config import DATABASE_PATH

import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
    c = connection.cursor()

    c.execute("""ALTER TABLE tasks RENAME TO old_tasks""")

    db.create_all()

    c.execute("""SELECT name, due_date, priority,
                status FROM old_tasks ORDER BY task_id ASC""")

    data = [(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3],
        datetime.now(), 1) for row in c.fetchall()]

 c.executemany("""INSERT INTO tasks (name, due_date, priority, status,
                    posted_date, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", data)


    c.execute("DROP TABLE old_tasks")
```

When the above script is executed, `data` takes in **4** sub lists and uses the data from them to create a new database.

Hope I helped!